# How Do I Dismiss a CardView

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

There is likely an obvious answer but not sure why I'm missing it.

```
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismiss(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    func dismiss(sender: FlatButton){
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I removed all unnecessary code for simplicity sake.  The btn2 code is all within a separate func.

Comment: Try changing `sender` to AnyObject

Comment: Doesn't work.  The dismiss func gets called, but I feel like I need to have `cardView.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` but when I try that, I get error `Value of type CardView has no member dismissViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

Use

```
self.cardView.removeFromSuperview()
```

That can be accessed in a separate func.

Answer (score 0):

I think you issue is with the selector it should look like this

```
btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismiss), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

No perimeters when assigning the action and it already know about the function no need for `viewController.`

Also it would help if we could see how you are presenting the card view. Depending on how you are presenting it will change how you get rid of it. If you card view is not a subclass of UIViewController then it would not have a `dismissViewController` function.